# How to get double records using LinQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm writing a query in .NET using LinQ technology. I want get all double records from field city. If the city count is equel to 1, then i don't want to get this in my results. Only 2 or more times. Does anyone know how I must write my query?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Comment: You need to show some code and read the guidance as to how to ask question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Such records are called "duplicates" in programmers' slang. Look for "find duplicates with linq" for solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
entities.GroupBy(e => e.City)
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
        .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Query syntax

```
from e in entities
group e by e.City into g
where g.Count() > 1
select g.Key
```